# How to make individual and centred R graphs

Tags: r, graph, formatting, time-series

I am having trouble formatting my graphs in R.

I am trying to plot the trend line in my time series of my 13 genes of interest.
Unfortunately, no matter what I try, all my graphs end up sharing a y axis, that is not labeled, and the titles of them are stuck inside the graphs, and not above.

I was wondering whether anybody knew why?

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 1:13) {
Symbol <- wantedhub$Symbol[i]
logCPM.obs.i <- logCPM.obs_wantedhub[Symbol,]
logCPM.fit.i <- logCPM.fit_wantedhub[Symbol,]
plot(days, logCPM.obs.i,  pch=16, main=Symbol, ylab="log-CPM")
lines(days, logCPM.fit.i, col="red", lwd=2) 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

[image: What my current graphs look like]

[image: What I want them to look like]

Comment: Try increasing your margins. `par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))` and re-plotting

Comment: If you can give a sample data, this can be handled mor elegantly using ggplot